# how add custom migration file and ruu php artisan passport:install

Tags: laravel, migration, installation, laravel-passport

when i run `php artisan passport:install` throw exception, user_id column is not found, i changed migration file user_id column to user_uuid

this is for a laravel api authentication.

```
C:\MAMP\htdocs\affter-05-07-2019\mo-backend>php artisan passport:install --force
Encryption keys generated successfully.

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `oauth_clients` (`user_id`, `name`, `secret`, `redirect`, `personal_ac
cess_client`, `password_client`, `revoked`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, Monash Personal Access Client, CvDHMWM9FYqiDeGRWsW2M3U5AVdi055FcwzvEShN, http://localhost, 1, 0, 0, 2019-07-12 20:29:16, 2019-0
7-12 20:29:16))
```

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to change the field from `user_id` to `user_uuid` because the passport is a library that expects that field to be there. you have two options here; 1. fork the passport library repository and make code change to support alternate id field OR revert the change to the user table migration and add a second field called `uuid` and use it that way.